# ERROR: Error installing fluent-plugin-mysql-bulk:

Tags: fluentd

Got this error while installing `fluent-plugin-mysql-bulk` like this:

```
gem install fluent-plugin-mysql-bulk
```

Here's the error:

```
ERROR:  Error installing fluent-plugin-mysql-bulk:
        The last version of mysql2 (>= 0) to support your Ruby & RubyGems was 0.5.3. Try installing it with `gem install mysql2 -v 0.5.3` and then running the current command again
        mysql2 requires Ruby version >= 2.2, < 2.7.dev. The current ruby version is 2.7.1.83.
```

Comment: Did you try as suggested in the message i.e. first run `gem install mysql2 -v 0.5.3` and then `gem install fluent-plugin-mysql-bulk`?

Comment: Yes i tried but still not working

Comment: What errors do you get after that?

Comment: Getting the same error @Azeem

Comment: That's strange. What do you see with `gem list | grep mysql2`?

Comment: iam working on windows that grep command will not work.